# Zooming based on Google Maps result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, openlayers

This is my current code:

```
$scope.search = function(){
    Request.googleAPI($scope.searchForm).then(function(data){
        console.log("Search result: ")
        console.log(data)
        var actualZoom = map.getView().getZoom();
        console.log("Zoom level: " + actualZoom)
        var point = [data.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng, data.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat];
        var size = /** @type {ol.Size} */ (map.getSize());
        view.centerOn(ol.proj.transform(point, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'), size, [size[0]/2, size[1]/2]);
        /*
        map.setView(new ol.View({
            projection: 'EPSG:4326',
            center: [long, lat], //long,lat
            zoom: actualZoom
        }));
        */
    })
}
```

I've tried using what is commented at the bottom (suggested on SO). I adapted it to only use "zoom", but it would turn my map white.

The Google Maps request contains the geometry-point location (lat/lng), but also the bounding box, which should determine the zoom level. How do I use this bounding box to properly update my map?

If you need to see some more code, here is the [complete script](https://acclimate-web.herokuapp.com/js/angular/controller.js) I'm using.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue (probably don't need the actual call to `.googleAPI`, just the data returned).

Comment: Here is my [complete code](https://acclimate-web.herokuapp.com/js/angular/controller.js). I do not think one needed anything more than what I've provided. Would you mind pin-pointing what was missing from this code so that I can learn from my mistake? Anyhow, I've found a solution and posted it. I can only accept it as the answer tomorrow, though.

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem.  Please provide a [mcve] **in the question itself**, not (just) a link to an external site.

Comment: It is a link to the actual code I'm working on, and last time I copy-pasted that much code, I was also warned that I shouldn't put that much information. Variables that might look obscure (such as `view` and `map`) are just as obscure to me since this is someone else's code I've been assigned to.

Comment: Your complete code is not (necessarily) a [mcve].  An external site (the code you are working on) will change and no longer be a useful resource for future readers of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved my problem with maths!

```
$scope.search = function(){
    Request.googleAPI($scope.searchForm).then(function(data){

        var point = [data.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng, data.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat];
        var size = /** @type {ol.Size} */ (map.getSize());
        view.centerOn(ol.proj.transform(point, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'), size, [size[0]/2, size[1]/2]);

        // To adjust Zoom Level
        var bound = data.data.results[0].geometry.viewport;
        var east = bound.northeast.lng
        var west = bound.southwest.lng
        var zoom = 9 - Math.floor(Math.log(Math.abs(west-east))/Math.log(2));
        map.getView().setZoom(zoom);
    })
}
```